# How to get the id of tr where id = value in array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a table with tr that have unique numeric ids set. I also have an array that contains the ids.

So basically I need to check if the tr id is in the array of values, if so add or remove a class from an element inside of it.

I have figured this out....

Comment: No one is going to write this from scratch for you. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Numbers are not valid for IDs in HTML. Please refer to this answer for naming conventions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: Not asking anybody to write it for me...Just not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

with:

`var ids = [ /* array of ids */ ];`

do:

`$('#'+ids.join(',#')).addClass('classy');`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var ARR = [ /* some ids */ ];

$('tr').each(function() {
  if (ARR.indexof($(this).attr('id')) != -1)
     $(this).addClass('hurray!');
});
```

Comment: `this.id` works perfectly well - `$(this).attr('id')` is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Older IEs don't have Array#indexOf.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Oh, of course, bad habit. :)

Comment: @Flo Yeah, one can easily implement it by himself... but who cares about older IE anyway? :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution assumes same class being add/removed to same elemnt within row. Passing true/false to toggleClass() determines add/remove

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var isInArray=$.inArray(parseInt( $(this).attr('id'), 10)) > -1;
    $(this).find(someEleemntSelector).toggleClass('className',isInArray );  
});
```